# save bmpData as jpg using adobe flex in air application

Tags: actionscript, flex4, air, store

i use the following code:

```
 protected function videoDisplay_playheadUpdateHandler(event:mx.events.VideoEvent):void
 {
    if(!captured && videoDisplay.playheadTime>=0){
    capture();
    }           
 }

 private function capture():void
 {

            var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(videoDisplay.width, videoDisplay.height);
            bmpData.draw(videoDisplay);

            captured = true;
            store(...); //????????


 }
```

in order to capture a frame from a videoDisplay object
1) is it correct or am i doing something wrong?
2) what can i do to store the bmpData as .jpg at my computer?

i am using flex4.5 and it is an air app...

any ideas??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The following code should help you

```
var jpegEncoder:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder(90);
var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData(videoDisplay.width,videoDisplay.height);
jpgSource.draw(this);
var fileReference:FileReference =  new FileReference();
fileReference.save(jpegEncoder.encode(jpgSource),"videoImage.jpg");
```

To use jpeg encode you need to have to import

import mx.graphics.codec.JPEGEncoder;

The above changes should be enough to allow the user to take a snapshot of a running video.
Please note, that with this the user will be prompted to select the location of the file.
Incase you want a silent save, let me know, I will put up the required code.

Comment: yes what i actually do is to record videos and store them behind the scenes..and because one can view the stored videos i want to have a thumb of each one do you understand? but the problem is when to call the above code?at playheadupdate handler?

Comment: That should not matter.When I said "file" I meant the user will be shown a "Save As" dialog for selection of location of the image that is going to be stored.

Comment: i have the following problem now: i want to scale the photo lets say to 150 width 120height and not BitmapData(videoDisplay.width,videoDisplay.height);
what can i do??

Comment: Allright.Here is what you need to do, take an <mx::Image> object in flex.Step A :Assing the normal image data to this image tag, Step B : Scale this image by simply changing the width, height, maintainAspect ratio properties Step 3: Take a snapshot of this image, as you did with the video, i.e passing the new height and width as one fifty/one twenty.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help but i didn't got enough from the answer i am a bit newbie around flex...my code is below could you help me a bit more? thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your application keep an image tag as follows.Most apt place should be just below the video.

```
<mx:Image scaleContent="true" width="150" height="120" maintainAspectRatio="false" id="myScaledSnapshot"/>
```

Now with this done, do the following changes in your code:

```
private function capture(filename:String):void
    {   
        var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(videoDisplay.width, videoDisplay.height);            
        bitmapData.draw(videoDisplay,new Matrix());

        var bitmap : Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
        var jpg:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder();
        var ba:ByteArray = jpg.encode(bitmapData);

        myImageSnapshot.source=ba;
        var jpegEncoder:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder(50);
        var imageSnapshot:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(this.myImageSnapshot,90,jpegEncoder);
        var imageByteArray:ByteArray = imageSnapshot.data;

        var newImage:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("KioskThumbs/"+filename+".jpg");

        fileStream = new FileStream();
        fileStream.open(newImage, FileMode.UPDATE);
        fileStream.writeBytes(imageByteArray);
        fileStream.close();
        captured = true;

    }
```

The above code really doesnt do anything special.
Its just using an image 'component' from flex, making it do the work for scaling the Video image, then taking the snapshot of this resized image component, and then writing it into a file.

Comment: Hello again!
I have a problem...the first time the image is captured from the scaled myImageSnapshot it appears to be black when saved and when i capture a new one the previous image is stored as it should be whats going on? any idea?

Comment: probably the image did not load properly after scaling.You can search for all the events available on the image tab in flex and use one of the loaded/complete events to trigger taking the next snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

My capture at last is:

```
        private function capture(filename:String):void
        {   
            var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(videoDisplay.width, videoDisplay.height);            
            bitmapData.draw(videoDisplay,new Matrix());

            var bitmap : Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
            var jpg:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder();
            var ba:ByteArray = jpg.encode(bitmapData);
            var newImage:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("KioskThumbs/"+filename+".jpg");

            fileStream = new FileStream();
            fileStream.open(newImage, FileMode.UPDATE);
            fileStream.writeBytes(ba);
            fileStream.close();
            captured = true;

        }
```

it works fine except the fact that i want  to scale the photo lets say to 150 width 120height and not BitmapData(videoDisplay.width,videoDisplay.height); what can i do to solve that?

Thanks a lot all of you!